# Add delay between sampling and checking

Tags: verilog, delay, system-verilog, assertion, system-verilog-assertions

I have written an assertion property. I want to add delay between sampling and checking action.

Basically below assertion says that assert_sig should be stable when sig1 or sig2 1.

```
property check_assert(assert_sig, assert_sig_dis);
    @(assert_sig)
    disable iff(!lane_assertion_enabled || assert_sig_dis)
    ((sig1!==1'b1) && (sig2!==1'b1));
  endproperty
```

Now the issue is assert_sig de-assert same time as sig1 asserts. That's why the assertion fails. I want to add a delay of 1ps between checking action and sampling. Is it possible? Or any other approach would also be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clocking blocks provide sampling skew

```
clocking as @(assert_sig)
input #1ps sig1;
endclocking
```

Then use `as.sig1` in your property.

Comment: Hi Dave, I tried with your suggestion but there were two things I want to mentioned
1. #1ps in the input gives a compilation error. I changed it to #1step, does that make sense?
2. Even after doing that I dont even see delay as.sig1 at @(assert_sig) changes.. 
Thanks

Comment: `#1ps` should have worked. See the LRM section 14.3 for an example